# Using paid version of Material UI with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

I purchased the full-stack bundle of Material UI components. I'm not sure how to use it with React. The instructions provided are:

- Press the download button near Material Kit Pro React product (this
  will download onto your computer a zip file)
- Unzip the downloaded file to a folder in your computer
- Open Terminal
- Go to your file project (where you've unzipped the product)
- Run in terminal
- npm install
- Then run npm start

Am I supposed to create my React app first? I'm not sure where to unzip this Material UI file. Unzipped, it creates a folder structure identical to a React app. Is this actually a necessary step?

I know that you can import via CDN—I've gone that route already. My issue is that I paid for this special version of Material for React, so I have all kinds of extra components—none of which are listed on their website. Is downloading the Material file just for my own reference?

I deleted all of the error messages, but I tried to create the React app from the Material file and I received errors regarding dependencies that were either outdated or not supported. I also received these same messages when I actually replaced my entire src/components folder in my React app with the src/components folder from the Material file. I've tried npm install, and I continue getting the error.

Apologies if this is a trivial question, but I'm a React newbie, and anytime I've used a CSS framework, I've always imported it via CDN. This is the first time that I downloaded an entire zipped folder, and again—it's more for reference than anything else. I don't want ALL of Material, but I do need to reference their CSS and actually see what these components look like since they aren't listed on their site, and I don't know all of the component names to be able to import them in the traditional import statements in the React app / components.

FWIW, I'm on a MacBook Pro running Big Sur—everything is up to date, including Node and all things Node-related. When I create any React apps, the versions are all the most current.

Thanks in advance, this is my first question, and I hope I did it right! :)

Comment: From the sounds of it, you may have paid for an outdated boilerplate with custom React components. In short, you're supposed to use that boilerplate as a foundation to build your app. Looking at the version history, it hasn't been updated in [almost a year](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-kit-pro-react/releases/tag/1.9.0), which is quite a long time in the dev world (especially for something that costs money).

Comment: What can you do? File an [issue](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-material-kit-pro-react/issues), or, ideally, get a refund. Since you're just starting out with React, I'd recommend using the [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) since it's a free boilerplate. Then you can use a free UI library like: [Ant Design](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce), [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html) or [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction) to name a few.

Comment: Ugh—that was the response that I knew was coming. Shame on me for not digging into their GH repo beforehand. It seems that the group selling this built it based off Material and Bootstrap. Anyway, I wrote to their support team, submitted an issue using their template on GH, and started getting the necessary things ready to dispute this charge on my credit card. Thanks for your response—it'll be a reminder for me to always do my due diligence!

Comment: No problem. If you don’t get a response from them, let me know. I may be to help you get it up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Creative Tim, the company selling UI kits based on Material Design, I was able to get a refund. You have to downgrade your Node version and likely other packages to get the React Pro Kit to work.

Answer (score 0):

To use Material Design UI elements with React, you would want to make them each into reusable components that can then be included as needed into a the UI for the app that you might currently be building.

Rather than do this yourself, there is already a [very comprehensive Material Design React library](https://material-ui.com/) where material elements have been made into components for whom you pass in `props` as desired to utilize them in such a way that fits the currently desired use case.

Here's an example where we're building a card that looks like this:
[image]

It makes use of several common Material Design elements which are available as Material-UI React components. As you can see, [each component has an API](https://material-ui.com/api/card/) and we can reference it to use each component as we build our applications UI.

[image]

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 140,
  },
});

export default function MediaCard() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
            across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
      <CardActions>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Share
        </Button>
        <Button size="small" color="primary">
          Learn More
        </Button>
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

If you intend, rather, to use the Material Design resources that you purchased to make your own React material Design components, I'd advise structuring such a library in the same modular and composable fashion.

It seems like the documentation to the component library you purchased [is here.](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-pro-react/#/documentation/tutorial) You would use it in the same way with a project you've already set up with. eg. `create-react-app`. Here's how you would include and use the [button](https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-pro-react/#/documentation/buttons) component. Make sure the file it is referencing is available for import into your project and then import it like this:

```js
import Button from 'components/CustomButtons/Button.js';
```

```js
<Button type="button">Default</Button>
<Button type="button" color="primary">Primary</Button>
<Button type="button" color="info">Info</Button>
<Button type="button" color="success">Success</Button>
<Button type="button" color="danger">Danger</Button>
<Button type="button" color="warning">Warning</Button>
<Button type="button" color="rose">Rose</Button>
```

You will find the styles for this component in
`src/assets/jss/material-kit-pro-react/components/buttonStyle.js`
and
`src/assets/jss/material-kit-pro-react/components/iconButtonStyle.js.`

My advice is to reinvent as few wheels as possible and always [see what libraries can do the job you're trying to do](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react) but (likely) with a more elegant, better tested, and more comprehensive solution than you have the time to build.

You might even check out something like [bit.dev](https://bit.dev/) which is a library of reusable modular components. Or [awesome-react-components](https://github.com/brillout/awesome-react-components) for a curated list of React components which meet the following criteria:

> - It solves a real problem
> - It does so in a  unique,  beautiful, or  exceptional way. (And it's not super popular and well-known... no point in listing those.)
> - It has recent code commits!

Comment: Thanks not sure if you read the question, but this isn’t really relevant

Comment: Yeah sorry, I wrote one answer and then re-read it and kinda added a section in the middle about how to use the ones you purchased-- is this not the docs for the stuff you purchased? https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit-pro-react/#/documentation/tutorial

I figured I'd mash them together since someone might find it helpful ‍♂️

I do think the resource links at the bottom may me helpful for you as well